# How to register the following datatype to allow serialization?

Tags: qt, qjson, custom-data-type

I am using [QJson](http://qjson.sourceforge.net/) to serialize a `QObject`-derived class. I am able to serialize the class itself without any problems, but when it comes to one of its members, I am having a bit of trouble.

The class is named `CProject` and it contains a property `files` which is defined as:

```
QList<CProjectFile> files;
```

When serializing an instance of `CProject`, I get a message in the console:

> `QMetaProperty::read: Unable to handle unregistered datatype 'QList<CProjectFile>' for property 'CProject::files'`

I read somewhere that I have to register the datatype, so I added the following after the declaration of `CProject`:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QList<CProjectFile>)
```

...and when that did nothing, I added:

```
qRegisterMetaType< QList<CProjectFile> >();
```

Nothing is working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how QJson works but perhaps it requires stream operators. Try as below after declaration of CProjectFile class

```
class CProjectFile
{
   ...
};

    Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(CProjectFile)

    qRegisterMetaType<CProjectFile>("CProjectFile");//Do this if you need signal/slots

    qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<QList<CProjectFile> >("CProjectFileList");
```

See also [QT Doc](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators) for stream operators